# How can I get the data used as key for group by

Tags: python, sql, django

```
id num tuser
1  2   user1
2  2   user2
3  3   user2
4  1   user4
5  1   user4
```

For example I have table like this .

Now I want to get the unique data appeared in `tuser` so, the result should be
`user1,user2,user4`

I guess it should be related with `group by`. So, I made this sentence.

```
p = m.MyTables.objects.all().values('tuser')
```

However how can I get the `user1,user2,user4` ?

Comment: Why use `GROUP BY`? Seems to be a better use case for `DISTINCT`

Comment: Because Distinct doesnt work in my mysql.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. Do you like to make the sum of the num column? If yes please use:

```
select sum(num), tuser from table group by tuser;
```

Instead of sum you can use each aggregation function like avg, min, max, etc.

If you jus want to have a list of all unique tusers please use:

```
select distinct(tuser) from table;
```

Comment: Thank you, however mysql doesn't use `distinct('something')` postgres can.

Answer (score 0):

I use `count` instead of `distinct` and it works.

Because distinct('something') works only on potgres, mysql not.

```
   m.MyTable.objects
    values('tuser').
    annotate(dcount=Count('tuser')).
    order_by())
```

Thank you very much for your help.